# How Linux determines which bashrc file to load when there're multiple of them?

Tags: bash, bashrc

For example, in my company, there're `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc.<username>`. However I don't know which one is automatically loaded everytime when it's started. Does it take everything or what's the rule to determine which one to pick up?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack exchange. For starters, you can find an answer here. I am fairly certain this is the information you are looking for.

Comment: The `.bashrc.<username>` file would be a local convention. Talk to your system administrators about it.